# Statement questions

Tags: logic

I have questions regarding statements and symbolic forms please tell me if i'm correct and if not why and whats the correct answers. Thanks.

Write the following in symbolic form:
'You'll love riding your bike if you have a good grasp, and you'll be able to pull tricks'

Let p = 'You'll love riding your bike' q = ' You have a good grasp' r = 'you'll be able to pull tricks'

ANS: (p -> q) ^ r [correct]?

Is this statement true or false?
Let p = true q = false r = true ~ r -> (p ^ ~q) = true [correct?]

Write the negation of the conditional statement:
If it is red, then it is not a grasshopper.

ANS: If it is not red, then it is a grasshopper [correct?]

Write the statement as an equivelent statement that does not use the if..then connective. Rememeber that p -> q = ~p ^ q.
If i am tired, then I'm going to bed.

ANS: I am not tired and im going to bed. [correct?]

Write the converse, inverse and contrapositive of the statement/
If you finish your food, you can go out and play.

CONVERSE: If you cannot go out and play, then you did not finish your food. [correct?] INVERSE: If you can go out and play, then your finish your food. [correct?] CONTRAPOSITIVE: If you did not finish your food, then you cannot go out and play. [correct?]

Write the following in the form of if a then b:
[The weather is bad when there's clouds.]

a then b: If there's clouds then the weather is bad.[correct?]

[You can ride your bike when the sun is shinning]

a then b: If the sun is shinning, then you can ride your bike. [correct?]

Is the statement true or false?
New Jersey is a state if and only if Florida is not a state - t/f? - true [correct?]

Decide wether the pair is contrary or consistent?
This person has been on all seven continents. This same person has never been to Brazil.

Contrary or Consistent? Contrary [correct?]

All help is truly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that

- if we set $p =$ 'You'll love riding your bike', $q =$ ' You have a good grasp' and $r =$ 'you'll be able to pull tricks'

The answer would be $(q\to p)\wedge r$.

- If $p =$ true, $q =$ false and  $r =$ true then

  $$\sim r\to \color{red}{(p~\wedge\sim~q)}\equiv F\to\color{red}{(T\wedge T)}\equiv F\to \color{red}{T}\equiv T$$